# Spring load ApplicationContext globally

Tags: java, spring

I am writing a java project using spring frame work. I have my bean.xml and I have defined my classes in my bean.xml. If I want to create an object, then I am creating application context and invoking required bean. For each and every class i am creating Application context and loading my bean.xml. I don't want to create this application context in each class. I want context object globally. 
Now i am using like this in each and every class:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring-config.xml");
```

But I need to load my bean.xml once and i want to call these context from anywhere(globally) to get the particular bean object.

> Note: I am not using java web project. I am using java project alone so i
>   dont have web.xml to load ApplicationContext globally.

Comment: You should basically only create the context in your `main()` method, then use the dependency injection. It wold be easier to explain if you gave us an example fo what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

According to spring's documentation you can load several XML configurations file at once, take a look:
[image]

I marked it for you in red.

So if you want to load `spring-config.xml` and `bean.xml`

then just do this:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring-config.xml", "classpath:beans.xml");
```

and if you want only to load `beans.xml` then:

```
 ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( "classpath:beans.xml");
```